# Gnuplot: align key directly under xlabel?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm am plotting multiple variables in gnuplot. I would like to centre the key under the plot, and centred on the plot area.

My current settings are:

```
set key outside
set key bottom center horizontal
```

This centres the key across the entire width of the plot. I would like to centre the key across the extent of the x axis; ie align it with the xlabel.

Is this possible in an automated fashion, or is tweaking involved?

Edit: This is all my mistake. I had asked gnuplot to plot a file that wasn't there, so its key was empty, but the space for it was still there, and that threw off the "alignment"; it was aligned with three entries, but not for the visible two.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what you got and what you want to achieve. You are talking about "under the plot" but "align with the y-label"...or do you mean x-label? An illustration would help very much.

Comment: @theozh I meant xlabel. I'll work up a figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which arrangment and alignment you are looking for...
also check `help key` for more options.

```
reset session

set multiplot layout 2,1 
set xlabel "This is the xlabel"

set key outside bottom center vertical
plot sin(x), cos(x), sin(-x), cos(-x)

set key outside bottom center horizontal
replot

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: That works. The issue was my mistake inasmuch as I had a script that was plotting a nonexistant file. The key was centred if that file was there.